# How to limit which NUMA nodes are used by SQL Server / SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssrs, numa

I have SSRS and SQL Server running on same physical server (2 NUMA nodes). 
How do you configure SQL Server and SSRS to use separate NUMA nodes?

I just didn't want SQL Data Engine to potentially consume 100% CPU resources and leave nothing for SSRS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have SSRS and SQL Server running on same physical server (2 NUMA nodes).
> How do you configure SQL Server and SSRS to use separate NUMA nodes?

You install a hypervisor, like [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/hyper-v-on-windows-server), and run SQL Server and SSRS in separate VMs.  The hypervisor can control the CPU and memory available to each VM.

In addition you may be able to run additional workloads on this hardware, and you can *move* the VMs to different servers whenever you want.

[Windows Server Standard Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/windows-server) includes Hyper-V and the rights to run 2 Windows Server VMs, so there's no extra cost.

Really no one should be running on bare metal in 2022.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can achieve that by using the **affinity** option of a resource pool available on [Resource Governor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor?view=sql-server-ver16). See this excerpt from the [Resource Pool Concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/resource-governor/resource-governor-resource-pool?view=sql-server-ver15#resource-pool-concepts) doc:

> - **AFFINITY**
>
> This setting lets you affinitize a resource pool to one or more
> schedulers or NUMA nodes for greater isolation of CPU resources. [...]

To use Resource Governor you need the [Enterprise Edition of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#RDBMSSP).